# Does someone deployed a custom activity on S3 or other AWS option?

Tags: journeybuilder, custom-activity, aws, azure

I am researching about the options to manage the webserver needed for custom activities (Journey Builder). I know the best option is Heroku, but in my company we've been using AWS and Azure for a while and we prefer something more cloud native and already connected to our systems (VPN, Direct Connect, etc).

The equivalent product of Heroku on AWS and Azure are Beanstalk and Webapps, but I'm thinking about something more simple, like S3 and Cloudfront, but I don't know is this possible becouse I'm not expert on JS and I know serverside javascript proccesing is required

Do someone tried something similar or is a better idea going directly to Beankstalk o Lambda (serverless)?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `S3` is for hosting only front end or static websites!

You cannot just use `S3` for custom activity as you will need to run a server side function to decode the `JWT` response and host `customActivity.js`

An AWS lamda for the service and the S3 for the front end assets should be fine!

Alternatively use the Beanstalk as you mentioned! With `Beanstalk` you can host your server side function for interaction with response from journey builder