# SFMC Journey Builder Custom Activity - deployment to AWS

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, custom-activity, aws

I'm currently building custom activity for Journey Builder. As of now I host it on Heroku but I'd like to move it to AWS. Does anyone done this and can tell me which AWS tools would be needed?

I've started to investigate this topic and the main problem that I see is that SFMC Installed Package require https link to the app. In Heroku it's directly https but when I checked AWS EB I see only http. Is there any simple solution to resolve this or I have to buy a private domain (which I would like to avoid...)?

Comment: Does this help? ... https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/334265/does-someone-deployed-a-custom-activity-on-s3-or-other-aws-option

Comment: @VishalKumarCV thanks a lot!